# How to arrange dynamical images?

Tags: android, image, paint

Can any body tell me to how to arrange on the image, if I change to one activity to another activity. My code is

```
public class Small extends Activity { 

// Instance variables
private Paint       mPaint,mBitmapPaint;
private MyView      mView;
private Bitmap  mBitmap;
private Canvas  mCanvas;
private Path    mPath;
public View onDraw;  

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.small);  

    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);          
    imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageview1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ic_launcer);      
    forword = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.forword);
    back = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back);
    relativelayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
    //select_color = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.color);



    DisplayMetrics metrics = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();         
    int w = metrics.widthPixels;
    int h = metrics.heightPixels;

    System.out.println(" width "+w);
    System.out.println(" height "+h);

    mView = new MyView(this, w, h);
    mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);    
    mView.invalidate();

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);       


    ImageButton coler = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.color);
    coler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int _color = R.color.red;
            new ColorPickerDialog(v.getContext(),new OnColorChangedListener() {

                  public void colorChanged(int color) {                     
                      mPaint.setColor(color);
                   }

               }, mPaint.getColor(), _color).show();

            //new ColorPickerDialog(v.getContext(),new OnColorChangedListener(), mPaint.getColor(), _color).show();
        }
    });

    ImageButton round = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.round);
    round.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Small.this,Flipper.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });      


    relativelayout.addView(mView);  
}

    ///////  colour changed function, getting value from ColorPickerDialog   ///////
    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
}

private void setimage(int i) {

    present = i;

    switch(i) {

    case 1:
        imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a); 
        imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow27);   
        break;
    case 2:
        imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b);
        imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow28);
        break;
```

flipper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >          
 <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >    
 </ViewFlipper>      
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >   
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/round"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round" />     
  </LinearLayout>      

 </RelativeLayout>
```

flipper.java

```
   public  class Flipper extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */    

    ViewFlipper Flipp;   

    public int[][] img_array=new int[][]{
             {R.drawable.flipimage_1_1,R.drawable.flipimage_1_2,R.drawable.flipimage_1_3, R.drawable.flipimage_1_4,R.drawable.flipimage_1_5,R.drawable.flipimage_1_6},
        {R.drawable.flipimage_2_1,R.drawable.flipimage_2_2,R.drawable.flipimage_2_3, R.drawable.flipimage_2_4},
        {R.drawable.flipimage_3_1,R.drawable.flipimage_3_2,R.drawable.flipimage_3_3, R.drawable.flipimage_3_4},
        {R.drawable.flipimage_4_1,R.drawable.flipimage_4_2,R.drawable.flipimage_4_3, R.drawable.flipimage_4_4},
        {R.drawable.flipimage_5_1,R.drawable.flipimage_5_2,R.drawable.flipimage_5_3, R.drawable.flipimage_5_4},
        {R.drawable.flipimage_6_1,R.drawable.flipimage_6_2,R.drawable.flipimage_6_3, R.drawable.flipimage_6_4},

    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.flipper);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        int selected=intent.getIntExtra("SELECTED", 0);
        int[] imgIds=img_array[selected];
        Flipp = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        for(int i=0; i<imgIds.length;i++)
        {
            ImageView imgView=new ImageView(this);
            imgView.setImageResource(imgIds[i]);
            Flipp.addView(imgView);
        }

        Flipp.setOnClickListener(this);  
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Flipp.showNext();   

        ImageButton round = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.round);
        round.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();

                //Intent i = new Intent(Flipper.this,Small.class);
                //startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming images to be displayed into flipper are on click on a- a1, a2. On B- b1, b2... so On. Change your code to following

Class Small:

```
public class Small extends Activity { 

    // Instance variables
    private Paint       mPaint,mBitmapPaint;
    private MyView      mView;
    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    public View onDraw;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private ImageView imageview1;
    private ImageButton forword;
    private ImageButton back;
    private RelativeLayout relativelayout;
    private int present;
    protected int past;
    protected int future;  

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.small);  

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);          
        imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageview1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ic_launcer);      
        forword = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.forword);
        back = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back);
        relativelayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
        //select_color = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.color);



        DisplayMetrics metrics = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();         
        int w = metrics.widthPixels;
        int h = metrics.heightPixels;

        System.out.println(" width "+w);
        System.out.println(" height "+h);

        mView = new MyView(this, w, h);
        mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);    
        mView.invalidate();

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);       
        present = 1;
        setimage(present);           
        back.setEnabled(false);     
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {       
                past = present -1;
                future = present +1;                        
                if (past==1) {
                    back.setEnabled(false);
                }else {
                    back.setEnabled(true);
                }
                if(past<=25) forword.setEnabled(true);

                setimage(past);             
                System.out.println("pastvalue"+past);                   
            }               
        }); 

        forword.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {   
                past = present -1;
                future = present+1;             
                if(future==26){                 
                    forword.setEnabled(false);
                }else {
                    forword.setEnabled(true);
                }
                if(future>=2) back.setEnabled(true);                                                    
                setimage(future);   
                System.out.println("futurevalue"+future);   
            }                           
        });     




        ImageButton coler = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.color);
        coler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int _color = R.color.red;
                new ColorPickerDialog(v.getContext(),new OnColorChangedListener() {

                      public void colorChanged(int color) {                     
                          mPaint.setColor(color);
                       }

                   }, mPaint.getColor(), _color).show();

                //new ColorPickerDialog(v.getContext(),new OnColorChangedListener(), mPaint.getColor(), _color).show();
            }
        });

        ImageButton round = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.round);
        round.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Small.this,Flipper.class);
                i.putExtra("SELECTED", present);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });      


        relativelayout.addView(mView);  
    }

        ///////  colour changed function, getting value from ColorPickerDialog   ///////
        public void colorChanged(int color) {
            mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    private void setimage(int i) {

        present = i;

        switch(i) {

        case 1:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a); 
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow27);   
            break;
        case 2:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow28);
            break;
        case 3:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.c);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow29);
            break;
        case 4:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.d);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow30);
            break;
        case 5:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.e);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow31);
            break;
        case 6:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow32);
            break;
        case 7:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.g);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow33);
            break;
        case 8:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.h);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow34);
            break;
        case 9:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.i);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow35);
            break;
        case 10:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.j);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow36);
            break;
        case 11:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.k);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow37);
            break;
        case 12:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.l);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow38);
            break;
        case 13:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.m);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow39);
            break;
        case 14:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow40);
            break;
        case 15:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.o);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow41);
            break;
        case 16:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.p);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow42);
            break;
        case 17:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow43);
            break;
        case 18:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.r);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow44);
            break;
        case 19:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow45);
            break;
        case 20:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.t);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow46);
            break;
        case 21:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.u);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow47);
            break;
        case 22:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.v);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow48);
            break;
        case 23:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.w);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow49);
            break;
        case 24:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.x);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow50);
            break;
        case 25:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.y);
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow51);
            break;
        case 26:
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.z);      
            imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow52);
            break;                  
        default:break;  
        }
    }   
    }
```

note changes I made in on click of round.
Flipper.class:

```
public class ClassB extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ViewFlipper Flipp;   
    public int[][] img_array=new int[][]{
            {R.drawable.flipimage_1_1, R.drawable.flipimage_1_2}, {R.drawable.flipimage_2_1, R.drawable.flipimage_2_2}.....

    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.flipper);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        int selected=intent.getIntExtra("SELECTED", 0);
        int[] imgIds=img_array[selected];
        Flipp = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        for(int i=0; i<imgIds.length;i++)
        {
            ImageView imgView=new ImageView(this);
            imgView.setImageResource(imgIds[i]);
                    imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            Flipp.addView(imgView);
        }

        Flipp.setOnClickListener(this);               
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Flipp.showNext();   

        ImageButton round = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.round);
        round.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();

                //Intent i = new Intent(Flipper.this,Small.class);
                //startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

remove imageviews from xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >          
 <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >    
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageview1" android:background="@drawable/flipimage_1_1" />  
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageview2" android:background="@drawable/flipimage_1_2" /> 
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageview3" android:background="@drawable/flipimage_2_1" />    
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageview4" android:background="@drawable/flipimage_2_2" />   
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageview5" android:background="@drawable/flipimage_3_1" />   
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageview6" android:background="@drawable/flipimage_3_2" />   
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageview7" android:background="@drawable/flipimage_4_1" />   
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageview8" android:background="@drawable/flipimage_4_2" />   


 </ViewFlipper>      
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >   
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/round"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round" />     
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want to call [Path.reset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#reset%28%29), not Path.isEmpty; the latter just tells you whether the Path is empty or not (and your code is simply discarding the result), it is not actually emptying the Path

Answer (score 0):

i will find my answer just iam use this my paint view is erase

```
            mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            mPath.reset();
            mView.invalidate();
```